# Sender-side deleting pending messages in mpsc channel

Tags: rust, channel, receiver, sender

Please is there a way for sender to delete pending messages sent to mpsc channel (or crossbeam-channel or equivalent) which have not been consumed by the receiver yet? Something like `sender.deleteAllPending()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with mspc which is "single consumer".

With crossbeam, you can have multiple receivers.
So you can clone and keep a receiver "sender side", so you can drain it.